# OpenStreetMap XAPI request for "Member Of"

Tags: openstreetmap, transportation

I'm trying to find a way to request public transportation info from the OSM XAPI. Those nodes can be best described as:

```
highway = *

member of = ( route = bus )
```

Is that even possible to do over the XAPI or do i need to query it from the planet data?

this is what i tried but with no success

```
http://open.mapquestapi.com/xapi/api/0.6/relation[route=bus][bbox=100.63584242503583,13.659388026297398,100.65300856273045,13.66877069028344]
```

Comment: you need to find the route number of the bus - example http://open.mapquestapi.com/xapi/api/0.6//relation%5Broute=bus%5D%5Bref=010%5D%5Bbbox=174.327,-37.236,175.324,-36.519%5D

Answer (score 1):

Use overpass query like this http://overpass-api.de

```
<osm-script> <union> <query type="relation"> <has-kv k="type" v="route"/> <bbox-query s="27.6839" n="27.7299" w="85.2885" e="85.3368"/> </query> <recurse type="relation-way"/> <recurse type="way-node"/> </union> <print/> </osm-script>
```